# Make close button(X mark) visible in PlaceAutocompleteFragment

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to make close button(X mark) visible in PlaceAutocompleteFragment which is used to display locations. How do I achieve this.

Below is the XML snippet:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/autocomplete_fragment_second"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
PlaceAutocompleteFragment mAutoCompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.feed_place_autocomplete_fragment);

ViewGroup autoCompleteFragmentView = (ViewGroup) mAutoCompleteFragment.getView();
    int clearButtonId = com.google.android.gms.R.id.place_autocomplete_clear_button;
    View mClearAutoCompleteButton = autoCompleteFragmentView.findViewById(clearButtonId);
```

This is how you get reference to that button, now you can change its visibility as you want.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it with a trick :)

```
autocompleteFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.place_autocomplete_clear_button).setPadding(0,0,0,55555);
```